# Are the two spans equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $x$,$y$ and $z$ be three linearly independent vectors. Explain, with justification, whether or not
$\operatorname{span}\{x,\,y,\,z\}=\operatorname{span}\{x+y,\,y+z,\,z+x\}$.

Comment: Can you write each of $x, y, z$ as a linear combination of $x+y, y+z, x_z$?

Comment: Hint: $2x = (x+y) + (x+z) - (y+z)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume W := v ∈ span{x+y, y+z, z+x} then

v = a(x+y) + b(y+z) + c(z+x)

= (a+c)x + (a+b)y + (b+c)z

so that if v ∈ W then v ∈ U, i.e. W ⊆ U. Assume v ∈ U then

v = ax + by + cz

= ((a+b−c)/2)(x+y) + ((b+c−a)/2)(y+z) + ((a−b+c)/2)(z+x) ∈ W

i.e. U ⊆ W.

Answer (score 0):

$x = \frac{1}{2}(x+y)-\frac{1}{2}(y+z)+\frac{1}{2}(z+x)$

$y = \frac{1}{2}(x+y) -\frac{1}{2}(z+x) + \frac{1}{2}(y+z)$

$z = \frac{1}{2}(y+z) -\frac{1}{2}(x+y) + \frac{1}{2}(z+x)$

So $x,y,z$ can be written as a linear combination of $(x+y),(z+x),(y+z)$ , hence the spans are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=x+y, b=y+z, c=z+x.$

Then $$\pmatrix{a\\b\\c} = \pmatrix{1&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&1}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$$
and
$$ \pmatrix{x\\y\\z}= \frac{1}{2}\pmatrix{1&-1&1\\1&1&-1\\-1&1&1}\pmatrix{a\\b\\c}$$

Since there is an invertible transformation from one set of vectors to the other, the spans are equivalent.